# Cheerio find all links in nested table

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to retrieve all links in a specific table but the selector does not seem to work. When I log the output to the console nothing appears, what am I doing wrong?

NodeJS code :

```js
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $("#TableWithRules").find("a").each(function(i, link){
                if(i == 10) return;
                console.log($(link).text() , $(link).attr('href'), true);
                
            });
```

The HTML code :

```html
<div id="TableWithRules">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><a GET THIS LINK ==> href="/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-5911">CVE-2020-5911</a></td>
        <td valign="top">In versions 3.0.0-3.5.0, 2.0.0-2.9.0, and 1.0.1, the NGINX Controller installer starts the download of Kubernetes packages from an HTTP URL On Debian/Ubuntu system.
</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><a GET THIS LINK ==> href="/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-27730">CVE-2020-27730</a></td>
        <td valign="top">In versions 3.0.0-3.9.0, 2.0.0-2.9.0, and 1.0.1, the NGINX Controller Agent does not use absolute paths when calling system utilities.

</td>
    </tr>

</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your selector is wrong, try it with:

```
$("#TableWithRules > table > tbody > tr > td").find("a").each(function(i, link){
    console.log($(link).text() , $(link).attr('href'), true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately, there isn't any output.

Comment: Try this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/node-js-sample-forked-t06qy?file=/index.js

Comment: The new link works fine ! I think that it doesn't work on the real website because the TableWithRules div is inside another div, but now I understand how it works.